# How to display detail information from database when primary id onchange

Tags: php, javascript

i have a table in mysql that contain courseid and coursename. I manage to fill the dropdown menu with courseid from table using php. Now i would like to display coursename each time user select courseid  in droplist for example when they select cd123 system will display "multimedia" (information from db based on courseid). Thanx

```
<body>
<select id="coursecodeID"> 
<?php
include ('config.inc');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM coursetest";
$rs = mysql_query($sql);
echo "<option>-Please select-</option>"; 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
{ 
echo "<option value=\"".$row['courseid']."\">".$row['courseid']."</option>\n  ";
}
?> 
</select>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `$row['coursename']` like this

```
echo "<option value=\"".$row['courseid']."\">".$row['coursename']."</option>\n";
```

This is a very basic question so I suggest you read on more tutorials/books/whatever you find useful.

You should know that the `mysql_*` functions are [deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated), meaning that they won't be developed any further. So in new code it is suggested to use [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) or [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.

Do you want the text to show somewhere outside of the dropdown?

Comment: it want it to be like this:
1. U have a dropdown contain student id1, id2, id3.. so when u use the dropmenu example u click id1, system will show student details such as name, age etc.. no submit or post require, just change selection in drop menu.. but details come from table with id as primary key.

Comment: yup show outside the dropdown based on courseid in dropdown but same page.. TIA

Answer (score 0):

Well you just need to do a SELECT Statement that gets the coursename by courseID

Example: select coursename from coursetest where courseid=(Here you put the selected index)

thats its

Feel free to ask me any questions

Comment: how to pass from selected index to select statement without posting the value to other page...

Comment: I think you'll have to use a bit of javascript for this. I'm not that good in javascript but what you'll basically have to do is checked when there a change in the select index like when you select one of this